# Unable to get email from Facebook Android SDK 4.x even if the user has granted the permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to get the user's email from Facebook Android SDK `4.3.0`

There are lots of questions about it but the marked answers tells that sometimes the user may not grant the permission.

I am using my Facebook acc for testing and I have granted the permission. Still I can not get it.

The code:

```
public static final List<String> FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday");

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    buttonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_fb_login);
    buttonLogin.setReadPermissions(AppConstants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS);
    buttonLogin.setFragment(this);

    buttonLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d("FacebookSDK", user.optString("email"));
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}
```

I doubt about Graph API version of the 4.3.0 SDK, but your advices may take me heaven.

Comment: Since API v2.4, you need to explicitly ask for the fields you want to get returned. I don’t see you doing that anywhere in your request that gets the user details.

Comment: It would be better that you show us how we explicitly ask for the fields in code... @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, I solved my own problem.

I should have expilcitly put the parameters that I want like below:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
        if (user != null) {
            Log.d("FacebookSDK", user.optString("email"));
        }
    }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```